# Format Log Output

Tags: powershell, logging, formatting

My script is backing up multiple SQL Server databases and I have it outputting each database and file name to a log file. I am unsure how to  align them in a column format.

```psh
Function LogWrite
{
  Param ([string]$logstring)
  Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}


$server = new-object ("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server")  "(Local)\sqlexpress"
$databases = $server.databases

$array = @($db1,$db2,$db3,$db4,$db5,$db6,$db7,$db8,$db9,$db10,$db11)
foreach ($element in $array)
{
  foreach ($db in $databases)
  {
    if($db.Name -like $element)
    {
      $dbname = $db.Name
      $dateTime = get-date -format yyyy_MM_dd
      $fullBackupFilePath = ($backupDirectory + "\" + $dbname + "_FULL_" + $dateTime + ".bak")

      Backup-SQLDatabase -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $dbname -BackupFile $fullBackupFilePath

      LogWrite "$dbname   -    $backupDirectory"
    }
  }
}
```

This is what it currently looks like:

```
Databases Succesfully Backed Up:

Aqm       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
Atlas       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
halive       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
hatrafficinfo       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
jtr       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
jtr2       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
mappa       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
mtf       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
PartOneClaims       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
ptfeedback       C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL


The following files were deleted as they were older than 14 days:

Aqm_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
Atlas_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
halive_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
hatrafficinfo_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
jtr2_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
jtr_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
mappa_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
mtf_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
PartOneClaims_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
ptfeedback_FULL_2015_08_19.bak
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another simple option is to use .NET formatting directives e.g.:

```
LogWrite ("{0,20}   -    {1,-60}" -f $dbname,$backupDirectory)
```

Where the format specifier is `{<placeholder-number>,[- for left-align]<field-width>}`.

Comment: this would probably be the route I would go here.

Comment: I had looked at this but the script kept failing - Yours on the other had was spot on!

Comment: Does `[` mean optional? Leaving out the second number results in an error, at least using PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: It is only the `-` that is meant to be optional.  That is, the `<field-width>` can be specified as either `20` or `-20` - the latter is used for left alignment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom PSObject.

```
$result = @{ DBName = $dbname; BackupDirectory=$backupDirectory }
$line = new-object PSObject -Property $result

$line
```

Comment: This is my preferred method as it ensures everything is an object going out, in the event you had to add on to the script and needed to do something with the value down the pipeline (e.g. write back to a table for reporting purposes).

Answer (score 1):

you could use an hashtable and show it with the format-table cmdlet.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
$server = new-object ("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server")  "(Local)"    
$databases = $server.databases                              

## some variables definitions
$db1 = "Model"
$db2 = "TempDb"
$db3 = "Master"
$backupDirectory = "c:\Backup\Etc"
$table = @{}
## 

$array = @($db1,$db2,$db3,$db4,$db5,$db6,$db7,$db8,$db9,$db10,$db11)            

foreach ($element in $array) 
{
 foreach ($db in $databases) 
 {
    if($db.Name -like $element) 
    {
        $dbname = $db.Name
        $dateTime = get-date -format yyyy_MM_dd 
        $fullBackupFilePath = ($backupDirectory + "\" + $dbname + "_FULL_" + $dateTime + ".bak")   

        $table.Add(($db),($fullBackupFilePath))
    }
 }
}

$table | Format-Table
```

The output result will look like :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple with padding as well.

```
LogWrite "$($dbname.padright(20)) $BackupDirectory"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to align text in PowerShell. The simplest is to separate the elements with tabs

```psh
LogWrite "$dbname`t$backupDirectory"
```

which would get you something like this:

```
Aqm     C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
Atlas   C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
halive  C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
hatrafficinfo   C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
jtr     C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
jtr2    C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
mappa   C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
mtf     C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
PartOneClaims   C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
ptfeedback      C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL
```

This won't align the columns perfectly, but better than before, and you get a tab-delimited file, that you can easily process with other tools without having to parse the values out of each line (if further processing is required/desired).

---

If you must have aligned columns in your log file, you could (as [@PeterSchneider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100217/1630171) suggested) create custom objects, which are automatically displayed in tabular format as long as they have less than 5 properties:

```psh
$prop = [ordered]@{
  DBName          = $dbname
  BackupDirectory = $backupDirectory
}
$obj = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop | Out-String
LogWrite $obj
```

which would create log entries like this:

```
DBName                                              BackupDirectory
------                                              ---------------
Aqm                                                 C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL

DBName                                              BackupDirectory
------                                              ---------------
Atlas                                               C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL

...
```

or like this if you remove the `Out-String`:

```
@{DBName=Aqm; BackupDirectory=C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL}
@{DBName=Atlas; BackupDirectory=C:\Mappa_Backup\FULL}
...
```

There are several downsides to this approach, though. For one, you get a header for each line written to the file, unless you echo the objects inside the loop and have your logging function read its input from a pipeline outside the loop. This would also require changing your `foreach` loop(s) to `ForEach-Object`.

```psh
Function LogWrite {
  Param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$logstring)
  Process {
    Add-content 'C:\temp\out.txt' -value $logstring
  }
}

...

$databases | ForEach-Object {
  ...

  $prop = [ordered]@{
    DBName          = $dbname
    BackupDirectory = $backupDirectory
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Out-String | LogWrite
```

Also, column widths may vary between runs, and values may be truncated depending on their length. Plus, if the objects have 5 or more properties, the automatic formatting changes to list format, so you'd need an additional `Format-Table` to maintain tabular output.

---

Arguably the best approach for getting aligned columns would be to use the [format operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx) (`-f`), as suggested by [@KeithHill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32100462/1630171):

```psh
LogWrite ('{0,-20} {1,-60}' -f $dbname, $backupDirectory)
```

The first number in each set of curly brackets is the index of the argument (0 refers to the first argument, here `$dbname`, 1 to the second, and so on), the second number defines the column width. The minus sign makes the column aligned to the left. Without it columns are aligned to the right.